# Change root of server block in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I moved to a cheaper VPS host in which my prior config was set up to display my files from /home/sam/www/website/index.html

But I can't seem to get this to happen on the new server, the default directory is /var/www/website/index.html

Any ideas on what to change on the config?  The majority is default

always displays default welcome to nginx html file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name samayres.net www.samayres.net;

    index index.html index.php index.htm;


    access_log /home/sam/www/samayres.net/logs/access_logs.log;
    error_log /home/sam/www/samayres.net/logs/error_logs.log;
    root /home/sam/www/samayres.net;
    error_page 401 /home/sam/www/samayres.net/error/401.html;
    error_page 403 /home/sam/www/samayres.net/error/403.html;
    error_page 404 /home/sam/www/samayres.net/error/404.html;
    error_page 500 /home/sam/www/samayres.net/error/500.html;
    error_page 501 /home/sam/www/samayres.net/error/501.html;
    error_page 502 /home/sam/www/samayres.net/error/502.html;
    error_page 503 /home/sam/www/samayres.net/error/503.html;
    error_page 504 /home/sam/www/samayres.net/error/504.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     }

# rewrite adminpanel to use https
    rewrite ^/adminpanel(.*)$ https://$host$uri permanent;

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests. Needed if wordpress is installed later
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

 # Directives to send expires headers
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
             expires 30d;
    }

# Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd
    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files index index.php $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
             }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the old provider used a directory tree of `/home/sam/www/website/`, while the new provider is `/var/www/website/`?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The default directory is /var/www/ and I can't seem to change it using the server block

Comment: @ShaneMadden correct, sorry I didn't make that clear, I edited the post now. it's displaying the default nginx index.html even though there is a server block stating another directory.

Comment: Your config looks fine. Did you reload nginx? Did you fix your DNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `server {` section, change:

```
root /home/sam/www/website;
```

to:

```
root /var/www/website;
```